# Effect of inductive effect on boiling point,melting point and dipole movement

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point, melting-point, dipole

In my book the following was written:-

> Inductive effect is a permanent effect operating in the ground state of the organic molecules and hence is responsible for higher melting point, boiling point and dipole movement of polar compounds.

How is inductive effect responsible for higher melting point, boiling point and dipole movement of polar compounds?

Why is inductive effect responsible for higher melting point, boiling point and dipole movement of polar compounds only?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure about melting and boiling points but things like polarity ,dipole moment and inductive effect are kind of interconnected.Inductive effect is a consequence of electronegativity differences.More inductive effect leads to more dipole moment but that also depends from one case to another.For example each of the $\ce{C-Cl}$ bonds in $\ce{CCl4}$ is highly polar but net dipole moment is 0 due to the fact that Dipole moments are added through vector addition and $\ce{CCl4}$ is tetrahedral.